# how to add images in dropdown list items

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi I want to put image along with some data in asp.net drop down list box.

Can somebody give me a sample code to achieve this functionality?

country flag + country name --> in the same list item

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Customizable-jQuery-Select-Box-Replacement-Plugin-wSelect.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available on a normal select. You have to use a plugin of some sort. Here's one - http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render